# How to write a movie with video AND audio using AVAssetWriter?

Tags: iphone, video, audio, export, avassetwriter

I want to export a movie with `AVAssetWriter` and can't figure out how to include video and audio tracks in sync. Exporting only video works fine, but when I add audio the resulting movie looks like this:

*First I see the video (without audio), then the video freezes (showing the last image frame until the end) and after some seconds I hear the audio.*

I tried some things with `CMSampleBufferSetOutputPresentationTimeStamp` (subtracting the first `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp` from the current) for the audio, but it all didn't work and I don't think it is the right direction, since video & audio in the source movie should be in sync anyway...

My setup in short: I create an `AVAssetReader` and 2 `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` (one for video, one for audio) and add them to the `AVAssetReader`, then I create an `AVAssetWriter` and 2 `AVAssetWriterInput` (video & audio) and add them to the `AVAssetWriter`... I start it all up with:

```
[assetReader startReading];
[assetWriter startWriting];
[assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

Then I run 2 queues for doing the sample buffer stuff:

```
dispatch_queue_t queueVideo=dispatch_queue_create("assetVideoWriterQueue", NULL);
[assetWriterVideoInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:queueVideo usingBlock:^
{
     while([assetWriterVideoInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
     {
         CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer=[assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
         if(sampleBuffer)
         {
             [assetWriterVideoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
             CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
         } else
         {
             [assetWriterVideoInput markAsFinished];
             dispatch_release(queueVideo);
             videoFinished=YES;
             break;
         }
     }
}];

dispatch_queue_t queueAudio=dispatch_queue_create("assetAudioWriterQueue", NULL);
[assetWriterAudioInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:queueAudio usingBlock:^
{
    while([assetWriterAudioInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
    {
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer=[assetReaderAudioOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
        if(sampleBuffer)
        {
            [assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
            CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
        } else
        {
            [assetWriterAudioInput markAsFinished];
            dispatch_release(queueAudio);
            audioFinished=YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}];
```

In the main loop I wait for both queues until they finish:

```
while(!videoFinished && !audioFinished)
{
    sleep(1);
}
[assetWriter finishWriting];
```

Furthermore I try to save the resulting file in the library with the following code...

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
if([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:url])
{
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
     {
         if(error)
             NSLog(@"error=%@",error.localizedDescription);
         else
             NSLog(@"completed...");
     }];
} else
    NSLog(@"error, video not saved...");

[library release];
[url release];
```

...but I get the error:

> `Video /Users/cb/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/E9865BF9-D190-4912-9248-66768B1AB635/Documents/export.mp4
>   cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12950 "Movie could not be played."
>   UserInfo=0x5e4fb90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Movie could not be
>   played.}`

The code works without problems in another program. So something is wrong with the movie...?

Comment: I wrote a post on stackoverflow to create a movie from an audio file and a picture array. Maybe some part of the code can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset

Answer (score 10):

```
-(void)mergeAudioVideo
{

    NSString *videoOutputPath=[_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dummy_video.mp4"];
    NSString *outputFilePath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];


    NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
    NSString *filePath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFile.m4a"];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];

    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         if (_assetExport.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {

          //Write Code Here to Continue
         }
         else {
            //Write Fail Code here     
         }
     }
     ];



}
```

You can use this code to merge audio and video.

Answer (score -3):

It seams that assetWriterAudioInput ignores sample buffer time for audio writing.
Do this way.

1) Write video track.

2) When done, mark it finished i.e. [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];

3) do [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:timeRangeStart];

3) instantiate audio reader and start writing audio.

Comment: startSessionAtSourceTime is for asset writer, not for an input. It's impossible to use it for managing inputs.