# Make movie file with picture Array and song file, using AVAsset

Tags: iphone, ios, video, audio, avassetwriter

I'm trying to make movie file using a picture array and an audio file. To make movie with a picture array i used the big post by zoul [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212). All is perfect, I have my movie with my picture. However when I try to add some audio tracks I have lot of problems. To understand I put my code :

When I call this method, picture array and song file are ready :

```
-(void) writeImagesToMovieAtPath:(NSString *) path withSize:(CGSize) size
{
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath];
    for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {
        if ([tString isEqualToString:@"essai.mp4"]) 
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,tString] error:nil];

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Write Started");

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                              error:&error];    
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];

    AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
    memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
    channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

    NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] ,AVSampleRateKey, 
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] ,AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:192000],AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                   [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)],AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                   nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                             assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                             outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    AVAssetWriterInput* audioWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                             assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                             outputSettings:audioSettings] retain];

    NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Big_Voice_1" withExtension:@"caf"];

    NSLog(@"%@",fileURL);
    AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL 
                                            options:nil] retain];


    AVAssetReader *audioReader = [[AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&error] retain];


    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];


    AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [asset.tracks objectAtIndex:0]; 

    AVAssetReaderOutput *readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:nil];

    [audioReader addOutput:readerOutput];                                             


    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    NSParameterAssert(audioWriterInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];


    //Video encoding

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //convert uiimage to CGImage.

    int frameCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[m_PictArray objectAtIndex:i] CGImage] andSize:size];


        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        int j = 0;
        while (!append_ok && j < 30) 
        {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) 
            {
                printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);

                CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) 10);

                //CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (kCFAllocatorDefault, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
                CVPixelBufferPoolRef bufferPool = adaptor.pixelBufferPool;
                NSParameterAssert(bufferPool != NULL);

                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (!append_ok) {
            printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
        }
        frameCount++;
    }

    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];





//Start a session:
        [videoWriter startWriting];
        [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

        CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

        //Write all picture array in movie file.

        int frameCount = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<[m_PictArray count]; i++)
        {
            buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[m_PictArray objectAtIndex:i] CGImage] andSize:size];


            BOOL append_ok = NO;
            int j = 0;
            while (!append_ok && j < 30) 
            {
                if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) 
                {
                    printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);

                    CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) 10);


                    append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
                    CVPixelBufferPoolRef bufferPool = adaptor.pixelBufferPool;
                    NSParameterAssert(bufferPool != NULL);

                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
                } 
                else 
                {
                    printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
                }
                j++;
            }
            if (!append_ok) {
                printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
            }
            frameCount++;
        }

        //Finish writing picture:
        [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
```

I finish write picture in movie file and I want copy audio in the file and I do this :

```
[audioReader startReading];

    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
    dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
    [audioWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue usingBlock:^
     {
         NSLog(@"Request");
         NSLog(@"Asset Writer ready :%d",audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData);
         while (audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
             NSLog(@"Ready");
             CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer = [readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
             if (nextBuffer) {
                 NSLog(@"NextBuffer");
                 [audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:nextBuffer];
             }
         }
     }
     ];

    [audioWriterInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
```

However the status of AssetWriterInput of audio file is always "NO".

My question : How to add audio to a video file using AVFoundation?

So please can someone help me by telling me if I forget something or if something is wrong.

Thank you very much

Comment: hi do you have any sample code for this

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I finally found how make movie with a picture array and an audio file. So if you want do the same thing I put my code here (be careful to memory):

- First make a movie file with your picture array use zoul's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212):

  ```
  -(void) writeImagesToMovieAtPath:(NSString *) path withSize:(CGSize) size
  {
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil];
    for (NSString *tString in dirContents) 
    {
      if ([tString isEqualToString:@"essai.mp4"]) 
      {
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,tString] error:nil];

      }
    }

    NSLog(@"Write Started");

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                            error:&error];    
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                 nil];


    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                           assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                           outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];




    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                   assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                   sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);

    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];


    //Video encoding

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //convert uiimage to CGImage.

    int frameCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<[m_PictArray count]; i++)
    {
      buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[m_PictArray objectAtIndex:i] CGImage] andSize:size];


      BOOL append_ok = NO;
      int j = 0;
      while (!append_ok && j < 30) 
      {
          if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) 
          {
              printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);

              CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) 10);

              append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
              CVPixelBufferPoolRef bufferPool = adaptor.pixelBufferPool;
              NSParameterAssert(bufferPool != NULL);

              [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
          } 
          else 
          {
              printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
              [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
          }
          j++;
      }
      if (!append_ok) 
      {
          printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
      }
      frameCount++;
      CVBufferRelease(buffer);
    }

    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];

    [videoWriterInput release];
    [videoWriter release];

    [m_PictArray removeAllObjects];

    NSLog(@"Write Ended"); 
  }
  ```
- After that you must put together movie file and audio file. To do this follow my code:

  ```
  -(void)CompileFilesToMakeMovie
  {
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSString* audio_inputFileName = @"deformed.caf";
    NSString* audio_inputFilePath = [Utilities documentsPath:audio_inputFileName];
    NSURL*    audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

    NSString* video_inputFileName = @"essai.mp4";
    NSString* video_inputFilePath = [Utilities documentsPath:video_inputFileName];
    NSURL*    video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:video_inputFilePath];

    NSString* outputFileName = @"outputFile.mov";
    NSString* outputFilePath = [Utilities documentsPath:outputFileName];
    NSURL*    outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];



    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];



    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
   ^(void ) {
       [self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath]; 
   }       
   ];  
  }
  ```

Sorry if there are some leak, I'm doing the optimization of memory.

Comment: @Rhythmic Fistman : I failed to use AVAssetWriter to write audio track with video track. It's a bad things ?

Comment: No, but I'm curious to know what was wrong with your original code.

Comment: I do not know. The sound was never added !

Comment: Hi all. I have a problem on iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1) on device log i read this error : "com.apple.mediaserverd[82] <Notice>: VTSelectAndCreateVideoEncoderInstance: no video encoder found for 'avc1'", someone please help me !

Comment: Does this approach survive the application going to the background and coming back? I have the problem that the app crashed if going to the background.

Comment: @TheRonin : I am trying to use our `-(void)CompileFilesToMakeMovie` method in my code but I am getting 'Export Failed
2011-12-26 17:23:40.536 AnimationApp[9261:707] ExportSessionError: The operation could not be completed'  can you please help me ?

Comment: @TheRonin : What is code of [self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath];

Comment: @Devang  [self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath]; is my method to save video in a document path.

Comment: Don't forget to link the frameworks: CoreMedia, CoreVideo and AVFoundation. Otherwise you'll get "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" errors.

Comment: the pixelBufferPool is nil so it doesn't work and I hit the assert. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: @anusha:could you help me out in this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168113/video-not-playing-audio-while-using-avassetwriter

Comment: in which conditions the pixel buffers are not appending in `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`

Comment: I am getting compile error because I don't have a method `[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[m_PictArray objectAtIndex:i] CGImage] andSize:size];` what should this method be? And does anyone know if this code still works with iOS8? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The AVChannelLayoutKey should point to an NSData instance containing an AudioChannelLayout.

Yours points to an NSNumber.

Comment: Thanks my first problem is done now. I edit my post in 10 minutes, if you have any solution to add some audio tracks to a video file…