# AVFoundation Alternative

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, avfoundation

In my app i insert an edited audio track over a video track and save the result in a single file (by an AVMutableComposition first and then by an `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`). I have used AVFoundation. Is there another framework that i can use to reach the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I post this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset) and I think there isn't other solution. I tried FFMPEG but AVFoundation is better.