# How to convert series of images into movie in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Can anyone tell me how do i convert a series of images into a movie,which i want to store in Camera role.we can use image Animation.
Sample Code Below.

```
  CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768, 1024);  
  UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc]; 
   [myAnimatedView initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    myAnimatedView.animationImages =appDelegate.imageArray; 
    myAnimatedView.animationDuration =  15.0; 
    myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0; 
    [myAnimatedView startAnimating];``
```

Now  i want to convert this image animation into  a movie.which i want to save in 
Camera Roll of ipad as a movie(Quick time Movie)

Thank's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the AVFoundation framework. For example checkout this post:

[Make movie file with picture Array and song file, using AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset)

As far as I know, using FFMpeg library will be a problem when trying to publish on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn and use FFMpeg library.