# How to create AVAsset from an Image

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm trying to edit video and images together using AVFoundation. However it seems `AVAsset`s cannot be created from an image file? Anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset) is a similar question with example code posted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make movie file with picture Array and song file, using AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm quite sure that AVAsset is prepared for Media with time, so AVAsset can not be created by image.

Comment: How did you end up mixing your photos and videos?  Did you use animated layers and sync them to the composition?

Comment: Yes,that's the solution I used, it seems AVFoundation is not convenient for photo slideshow Job~

Comment: how to use animated layers to append a image with a video