# How to merge video and recording and make single video

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6

I want to make video from images and merge the recording sound with this video.

After a lot of R&D and samples i am unable to merge both, till now i am only able to create video from images.

Can any one tell me the concept behind merging video and audio.
 I am using **xcode 4.5** and **iOS 6**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Must Search the Answers Previously Answered in StackOverflow.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset/6094407#6094407) is an Answer Describing Adding Audio to a movie.

And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) is an answer for Creating Movie from images.