# Mac Merge an Audio and Video file together

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audio, ffmpeg

So I have a audio and video clip that are the same lengths together and I would like to merge them into one file to make a video clip with sound.

I found this answer, but it is for iPhone it seems: [Merging Audio with Video Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909400/merging-audio-with-video-objective-c)

Basically, what I want to do is this command from FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i TestRecording-20140363110156.mov -i 1393956048.wav -vcodec copy out.mov
```

Is this possible? If not, can I just include the compiled ffmpeg file into my project and call that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly include the compiled ffmpeg in your app bundle.  I would use `NSTask` to run the command.  You can find the path of the embedded ffmpeg with this code:

```
NSString ffmpegPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ffmpeg" ofType:@""];
```