# how to put my image in center?

Tags: iphone

I have created video using image array and audio file with the help of AVAsset.
I followed below link for help:
[Make movie file with picture Array and song file, using AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset)

but In new video ,image is not in center. how to put my image in center?

Comment: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/107325-add-video-watermark-problems.html

Comment: I guess your app should have be crash if your image is in improper resolution input while processing video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because of video size you passed inside video settings are not in ratio...

```
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:standardWidth], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:standardHeight], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];
```

You can check one near to ur required resolutions
[standard video resolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions)