# IOS - saving pictures to be replayed into one video

Tags: ios, arrays, image, video, uiimageview

If anyone has used the app Flipagram, they take pictures that the user submits and then the pictures are replayed all in one video. I need help with how I go about doing that. I'm not to good with integrating camera use and If anyone knew how to help, i would appreciate it.

Comment: please refer this [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment you can convert image-list to videos.

Another solution can be :
If you can access those images, then you can use `UIImageView` and animate the series of images using `animationImages` method. 
Along with this, you can also play audio using `AVAudioPlayer` if you need to play a sound.