# Combining an audio file with a video file

Tags: ios, audio, video, ffmpeg, multiplexing

I have two files: one audio and one video (mp4).

I want to create from those two files, one video file that will contain both the audio and video output. The main issue is the synchronization between both of those recorded files. There's a man speaking, and the movement and sound need to line up.

I heard about the FFmpeg library for iOS but didn't found any good information about it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem. Are you trying to put video editing functionality into your app?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at AVFoundation, specifically AVAssetWriter.  They should do what you're needing to do, and unlike ffmpeg, they'll take full advantage of any hardware acceleration available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a movie with video AND audio using AVAssetWriter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481268/how-to-write-a-movie-with-video-and-audio-using-avassetwriter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should use `AVFoundation` to merge audio and video into one file. This answer shows how to do it:

[How to write a movie with video AND audio using AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464736/348796)